python tkinter entry is not showing
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msg

root = Tk()
users = {'pawan': '123'}

userval = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
uservals = StringVar()
passwords = StringVar()

def submitForm():
    if userval.get() in users:
        root.destroy()
        main = Tk()
        main.geometry("200x200")
    else:
        msg.showinfo(message='Invalid User or Password')
    print(users)

def signupForm():
    print(uservals.get())
    print(passwords.get())
    

root.geometry("655x333")
root.title("Library")

tframe = Frame(root, bg="black")
tframe.pack(side="top", fill="both")

heading = Label(tframe, text="Welcome to Our library", bg="red", borderwidth=12).pack()

fframe = Frame(root, width=400, height=200)
fframe.pack()

user = Label(fframe, text="Username").grid()
passw = Label(fframe, text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)

userin = Entry(fframe, textvariable=userval)
userin.grid(row=0, column=1)
passwin = Entry(fframe, textvariable=password, show="*")
passwin.grid(row=1, column=1)

loginb = Button(fframe, text='Login', command=submitForm).grid(row=3, column=0)

def signup():
    sign = Tk()
    sign.geometry("400x200")
    Label(sign, text="Enter Email").grid()
    Label(sign, text="Enter Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
    si = Entry(sign, textvariable=uservals)
    si.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Entry(sign, textvariable=passwords, show="*").grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(sign, text='Signup', command=signupForm).grid(row=3, column=0)

Button(fframe, text='Signup', command=signup).grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()


this is my code in this i want to print entry values (textvariable=passwords and textvariable=uservals) of signup function in signupForm and after that i can use as i want but when I click the butoon only empty thing is printing in shell or in debugging area

Use Toplevel() to sign = Toplevel()
